# Does the Google Play store always show an app's update date and version consistently?

Tags: google-play-store, pokemon-go

I thought the update date and version should be consistent. But the [note of the update of Pokemon Go](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-110616/) says version 0.45, updated Nov 6, 2016, but if I go to Google Play store, it says updated Nov 6, but version 0.43?

What I mean is, shouldn't it have the updated date of earlier date, and version 0.43, OR showing BOTH the newer updated date and version 0.45? (update date and version number consistent with each other).

Screenshot on Google Play website:
[image]

Comment: Related and probably duplicate http://android.stackexchange.com/q/155018/131553

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate

Comment: I also want sure so didn't Mark it duplicate but the solution may help