# Google play store reviews: For an older version

Tags: google-play-store

Whilst reviewing a certain application  on Google play store I came across an odd comment "For an older version" which  seemed to have originated  from several users and this  confused  me whether all the users had  posted the same comment complaining the "old version was better" or it means something else.

It is specifally from users of maybe has something to do with the developer, but either way this still remains vague to me. I just wish to know what exactly do they mean with such a review comment?

Comment: Sometimes I regret when having updated an app, only to find the older build had better features I wanted or UI, so I was also thinking to post the same comment "For an older version" so that the developer brings back cool features and UI of older build whilst improving bugs etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means that the comments posted by reviewers pertain to older version of the app , immaterial whether they are good or bad

Other comments which don't have this comment are for the current version, so that's what you need to pay attention to (Bugs in older versions may have been fixed as is usually the case)

As clarified in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118566/google-play-app-reviews-and-specifications), there can be only rating for app by a user , irrespective of the versions. Hence the need to differentiate old reviews from current version reviews

Seeing wbogac z's comment, found [this blog](https://www.androidcentral.com/no-developers-cant-delete-your-app-review?amp) which mentions that their is a separate versioning that is not visible to the users and older reviews are likely based on that.

**Edit:** See this for versioning details from a developer point of view 
[App updation- Google Play Store wants to update an older version of app when latest version is already installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/155018/131553)

Requesting developers to confirm or correct

Comment: To be frank, if the version is not "for an older version", the best that can be said about version is "indeterminate". You cannot assume the converse is true.

Comment: @wbogacz@beeshyams don't you think writing something like, This review was for an older version of the application released on MM/DD/YY. The most recent  update was released on MM/DD/YY." or something like that, at least one can be sure about the meanng as its not biased

Comment: OK I will check and let you know. Sometimes I regret when having updated an app, only to find the older build had better features I wanted or UI, so I was also thinking to post the same comment "For an older version" so that the developer brings back cool features and UI of older build whilst improving bugs etc :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70905/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-xavier-fakerat).